# How can I deal with the ICE60 warning in WiX?

Tags: wix, warnings

I have created a WiX project that installs a bunch of different EXEs and DLLs. Unfortunately when I build the project I receive the following warning for each one of them:

> ICE60: The file fileName is not a
>   Font, and its version is not a
>   companion file reference. It should
>   have a language specified in the
>   Language column.

I have found examples and possible solutions for this and each time it is suggested to set the DefaultLanguage tag to 0 in order to fix the warning. Once doing that I then get this warning:

> The DefaultLanguage '0' was used for
>   file 'fileName' which has no language
>   or version. For unversioned files,
>   specifying a value for DefaultLanguage
>   is not neccessary and it will not be
>   used when determining file versions.
>   Remove the DefaultLanguage attribute
>   to eliminate this warning.

How can I handle this warning?

Comment: Maybe you could show the parts that give the warning/

Comment: It is simply when inserting a file into the installer. It is because the exes are generally older and do not have a language within them. problem there is I can't modify them at the moment.
<File Id="FileName" Name="FileName.exe" Source="thePath\FileName.exe" DiskId="1" KeyPath="no" />

Comment: So what else is in the component? And what is the KeyPath of that component?

Comment: Created separate components and set the file keypath to yes and received the same result. Good comment though. Got me thinking. The files are all in their own components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I beileve you are stuck with the warning until the executables are updated. Not helpful, I know, but I would focus on fixing the executables rather than trying to hack the Windows Installer.

Comment: Unfortunately that is what I'm stuck with thanks for the response.

Comment: Is this still the case?  The dll isn't mine so I cannot fix the issue and recompile unfortunately.

Comment: In my scenario I'm using a font file, and have this same error, so @RobMensching how can I "focus on fixing the [file]" rather than trying to hack the installer. I don't understand what this is saying. In my case the file IS a font.
<Component Id="ARDESTINEttfComponent" Guid="(removed)">
        <File Id="ARDESTINE.ttf" Name="ARDESTINE.ttf"
        Source="$(var.SourceDir)\ARDESTINE.ttf"
        DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>

Comment: In Wix 3.5 at least you can suppress this warning using the light `-sice:ICE60` option. In the wixproj file this can be done by adding `<SuppressIces>ICE60</SuppressIces>` into a property group.

Comment: @patthoyts Your comment should be an answer, and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use something besides Wix.  Having an test for a condition which the developer has no means to solve anyway, is a fruitless search for perfection that just results in wasting peoples time.  In the end, your installer will work fine with this warning, and the warning being there will lead to you missing some other warning because you over looked it in the stream of useless output produced by this warning.

There is no value in demanding language when there is no net use of that language to fix the users life.  The executable still run, they still produce the same results and they still have no support for language.  So, why would this test, with an unquenchable warning, really add value to the developer or users life?