# Can't suppress WiX warning LGHT1076

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5, wix3.8

I'm using WiX tool to harvest files and create an installer

The `heat` linker produces some warning LGHT1076, I tried adding `-sw1076` to the command line to suppress the warning id 1076 but the warnings still show up on the console

**EDIT**

here the actual warning as displayed on the console:

> components.wx
>   s(436): warning LGHT1076: ICE60: The file
>   fil7B3FA00E2521DBF8AC02D1673A643A1A is not a Font, and  its version is
>   not a companion file reference. It should have a language specified in
>   the Langu age column

Comment: Can you post the exec error message?

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky I made an edit to the question

Comment: What file is this? also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298575/how-can-i-deal-with-the-ice60-warning-in-wix

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky I just want to suppress the warning. I thought I should set an option on the command line like on a normal linker

Comment: In project properties, go to Tool Settings and click Suppress ICE validation and add ICE60.

Comment: what about suppressing it from the command line? can it be done?

Comment: From the heat command you cannot do that, but if you run the light command you can use the -sice:ICE60 flag.

Comment: Does this answered your question? I want to post it as answer so people don't look the answer in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wix project editor does not save suppress warnings values into the file. You need to add them manually. Open wixproj file in Notepad and add the following property group:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SuppressIces>ICE03</SuppressIces>
    <SuppressSpecificWarnings>1076</SuppressSpecificWarnings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Add it where? Inside what other XML tag?

Comment: @ixe013: It must be placed inside the `Project` XML tag. Same level as other `PropertyGroup` or `ItemGroup` tags.

Comment: I got a similar warning: **light.exe(0,0): warning LGHT1076: ICE03: String overflow...**.
Either of the elements `<SuppressSpecificWarnings>1076</SuppressSpecificWarnings>` and `<SuppressIces>ICE03</SuppressIces>` is enough to suppress it. The other tag is not needed in my case.